# How to convert Object to List<string> in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, object

I have a `List<string>` in Model.
When I write a *html helper*, I can get the data from `metadata.Model`, which is an object

```
// this is from MVC3 (namespace System.Web.Mvc -> ModelMetadata), I did not write this
// Summary:
//     Gets the value of the model.
//
// Returns:
//     The value of the model. For more information about System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata,
//     see the entry ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 2: ModelMetadata on Brad Wilson's
//     blog
public object Model { get; set; }
```

My question is: how to get `List<string>` from an `Object`?

Comment: What is the actual type of the object?  It wouldn't make sense to "convert" _any_ object to some list of strings.

Comment: You mean typecast? obj as List<string> ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the underlying type of the `object` variable is `List<string>`, a simple cast will do:

```
// throws exception if Model is not of type List<string>
List<string> myModel = (List<string>)Model;
```

or

```
// return null if Model is not of type List<string>
List<string> myModel = Model as List<string>;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, there is a difference between the two examples, the first will throw an exception if the cast doesn't work, whereas the second will just assign `null` to the left operand.

Comment: you commented a second after I update my answer with that.  :P

Comment: ohh, thanks, this works. I was mislead by this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject :( and tried all kinds of complex xxx.