# How to iterate over items of a list when I only have access to the object of that list and dont know the type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list

Somewhere in my code I have an object that I already know that is a list. But I don't know the type parameter of that list. I need to iterate over it's items. I tried to cast that object to a list of objects but it didn't help me:

```
List<Object> objList = (List<Object>)(dataModel.Value);
foreach (var item in objList)
{
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

In the above code, the `Value` property of `dataModel` is a list of `XYZ` values, but it throws an exception when I run this code. It says that, it could not cast `XYZ` to `Object`.

Is that possible to do some deserialization and do the job over deserialized objects?

Comment: what is the type of dataModel.Value ?

Comment: Does it work if you case to `IEnumerable<Object>`?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject? Try using `IList`.

Comment: Why do you want to cast it?? It should work just fine with `foreach (object item in dataModel.Value)` shouldn't it?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis `dataModel.Value` is a list. But I don't know type of items in that list.

Comment: @VikasGupta - That would only work if `dataModel.Value` is declared as a list. If it's declared as `object` your suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: @VikasGupta - Of course it is a list, but `dataModel.Value` is obviously not declared as a list - if it were the OP wouldn't have needed to cast it in the first place.

Comment: In my application I obtained `datamodel.Value` from another assembly using reflection. I extract `FieldInfo` of all items in runtime, but in compile time I do not have access to the type parameters, because I have reflected the `dataModel` from an external assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should cast to `IEnumerable<object>`, or even just `IEnumerable`.

A `List<string>` is not a `List<object>` as generic variance doesn't apply to classes, and a `List<string>` is not an `IList<object>` as `IList<T>` is not covariant. (It can't be, due to operations which *accept* a `T`, such as `Add`.)

However, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T` which is exactly what you want in this case - but only if your value is a list of *reference* types; covariance doesn't work with type arguments which are value types... so a `List<int>` isn't convertible to `IEnumerable<object>`. It *is* still convertible to `IEnumerable` though, so the following code gives you the most flexible solution:

```
var items = (IEnumerable) dataModel.Value;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `List<Something>` does not derive from `List<object>` it derives from `object` but not from `List<object>`, this makes sense as it could be very type unsafe. You can always treat a `List<int>` as an `object` for example, but if you could treat it as a `List<object>` you could then call `.Add("test")` and end up with a `List<int>` containing a `string` violating type safety.

However recent .net versions added covariance and contravariance, it doesn't make sense on `List<T>` but it DOES make sense on `IEnumerable<T>` (as you can't "add" to an `IEnumerable` but only enumerate it, it's very fine to enumerate items of arbitrary types as `objects`).

So you can cast to the interface:

```
IEnumerable<Object> objList = (IEnumerable<Object>)(dataModel.Value); // This works, List<whatever> is IEnumerable<whatever>, IEnumerable<whatever> can safely be cast to IEnumerable<object>
```

Or you can cast the individual items themselves if you want to stick to a List by creating a new List as such:

```
List<object> objlist = dataModel.Value
     .Cast<object>() // every item will be cast to object
     .ToList(); // then make a new list out of it, this is type safe as the original List<whatever> is not affected.
```