# Why does the explicit conversion of List<double> to IEnumerable<object> throw an exception?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, ienumerable

According to this [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) `IEnumerable` is covariant and this is possible to implicitly cast a list of objects to an enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<String> strings = new List<String>();
IEnumerable<Object> objects = strings;
```

In my own code i have written a line of code that works perfect when item type of the list is class `Point` (Point is a simple class with three properties double x,y,z):

```
var objects = (IEnumerable<object>)dataModel.Value;
// here property Value is a list that could be of any type.
```

But the above code returns the following exception when item type of the list is `double`:

```
Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Double] 
to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Object].
```

What is the difference between `string` and `double` and what causes the code to work with `string` but not with `double`?

### Update

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715820/764809) we could simply cast a list to `IEnumerable` (without type argument) so as I only need to iterate over items and add new items to the list ( Actually I do not need to cast items of the list, at all). I decided to use this one:

```
var objects = (IEnumerable)dataModel.Value;
```

But if you need to cast items of the list to `object` and use them, the answer from Theodoros is the solution you most follow.

Comment: Covariance only applies when you're *casting*. For value-types, a *conversion* is needed and variance has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @haim770 I'm not sure I agree with that. There still needs to be an *implicit/identity conversion* between the types, as for the spec: *The purpose of variance annotations is to provide for more lenient (but still type safe) **conversions** to interface and delegate types. To this end the definitions of implicit (§6.1) and explicit conversions (§6.2) make use of the notion of variance-convertibility*

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, What exactly is it you don't agree with? I can't find anything in the spec you mentioned that contradicts my comment.

Comment: @haim770 Perhaps I didn't understand your comment properly, not sure what you mean when you say "Covariance only applies when you're casting". There is no casting needed here.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Perhaps we first need to clarify the distinction between *casting* and *conversion*. As far as I understand, casting doesn't change (or create a new) value of the object. It only changes the way the compiler treats it. With conversion, you *do* end up with a new value (internally, that can be a result of an implicit/explicit casting but it's still a new value).

Comment: @haim770 I see what you mean. AFAIK, there are conversions where the compiler ends up treating the object differently without producing a new value, such as *identity* and [*implicit reference*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691284(v=vs.71).aspx) conversions, for example. Those implicit reference conversions are what apply to co/contravariance, and why value types don't actually apply to the variance game.

Comment: _Very_ related thread: [Why covariance and contravariance do not support value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Constructed types of variant interfaces (such as `IEnumerable<out T>`) are variant only for reference type arguments, because their implicit conversion to a supertype (such as `object`) is a non-representation-changing conversion. This is why `IEnumerable<string>` is covariant.

Constructed types for value type arguments are invariant, because their implicit conversion to a supertype (such as `object`) is representation-changing, due to [the boxing that's required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111857/why-do-we-need-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c). This is why `IEnumerable<double>` is invariant.

See the [relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

A possible workaround is to use LINQ cast:

```
var sequence = list.Cast<object>();
```

This will first check whether the source is assignment-compatible to the `IEnumerable<TResult>` that you are trying to cast it to.

- If it is assignment-compatible (as is the case for `T` being `string`, for example), [it will return the initial source directly](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) (which is the ideal case, performance-wise).
- If it isn't assignment-compatible (as you have found out is the case for `T` being `double`, for example), [it will create a projection that attempts the conversion manually for each individual element](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365).

Comment: This means that I can convert `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>`  But this is not possible to convert `List<int>` or `List<double>`  to `IEnumerable<object>` ? If this is the case what is the alternative way? Thanks for your fast response

Comment: That depends what you want to do with it. You can always wrap it and expose the new enumerator.

Comment: @a.toraby You'll need to explicitly cast those values to an `IEnumerable<object>`: `IEnumerable<object> objects = dataModel.Value.Cast<object>();`.