# Access List inside Object

Tags: c#

I have an object that is a List

```
object myobject; //
```

I know that myobject is a

```
List<double> or List<string>
```

I need to print something like this;

```
for (int i = 0; i < myobject.count()+ i++)
{
    string str = myobject[i].toString();
}
```

But I don't know how to count objects, and acess some myobject[i]

Comment: You can't access myobject yet because it's of type object. Simply cast it to whatever collection type it is before working with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast received object to a List<object> or IEnumerable<object>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is cast it to the list type you're expecting so if you know its gonna be a List of string you do something like this :

```
List<string> myList = (List<string>)myobject;

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count(); i++)
{
    string str = myList[i];
}
```

This is for if you really don't know if the list you're getting is double or string :

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>();
List<double> myDoubleList = new List<double>();

try {

    myStringList = (List<string>)myobject;

    for (int i = 0; i < myStringList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myStringList[i]);
    }
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
    myDoubleList = (List<double>)myobject;

    for (int i = 0; i < myDoubleList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myDoubleList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But he doesn't know if it's a list of string

Comment: Fair enough i added a second way if he doesn't know which it is.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest extracting a generic method:

```
// think on turning the method into static  
private void PerformList<T>(List<T> list) {
  // try failed
  if (null == list)
    return;

  // foreach (var item in list) {...} may be a better choice 
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) {
    string str = list[i].ToString();

    ...
  }
}

...

object myobject = ...;

// Try double
PerformList(myobject as List<double>);
// Try string
PerformList(myobject as List<string>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of `myobject` there isn't any property called `Count`. You could try something like the following:

```
var list = myobject as List<int>();
if(list == null)
{
    // The cast failed. 
    // If the method's return type is void change the following to return;
    return null; 
}
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    string str = list[i].toString();
}
```