# ASP.NET MVC Web API: passing in a value that can either be a string or an array of ints

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

The model property in the response model is

```
object value { get; set; }
```

When I send a json object where value is a string, it assigns perfectly to value, but when I pass up an array it turns into "object{}" and any way I try to parse it to any sort of enumerable it winds up as null.

To get around this as of now I'm sending up a stringified array, then deserializing it on the server, but it doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Comment: Share code for your controller. What version of .net are you using?

Comment: This might help you.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632570/cast-received-object-to-a-listobject-or-ienumerableobject)